# Strange error with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

The below code helps me to use `selenium` to navigate to a page and click on "View All Companies" button

```
path_to_chromedriver = r'C:\Users\chromedriver.exe'  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)
driver.get(r'http://sgx.com/wps/portal/sgxweb/home/company_disclosure/stockfacts')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)

# locate and switch to the iframe
iframe = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#mainContent iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

# wait for the table to load
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.companyName')))

# Select All Companies
element1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span[data-name*="all-companies"]')
element1.click()
time.sleep(5)
```

However, when I tried `print(driver.page_source)`, it would print out the source first, then present an error message as such:

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Any advice?

Comment: can you check same with `Firefox` webdriver?

Comment: Odd..., running your code on osx in Chrome & Firefox, using Selenium 2.52.0, works just fine.

Comment: Could it be because i'm running on windows 10?